# How to alias commands on Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am using Unix and Windows machines, and I want to make the Command prompt behave in a way similar to my Unix Teminals.

One of the things is the aliases that I am used to on Unix.

For example - I am used to

```
alias p 'ls -lt'; pwd;
```

How can I set this alias on Windows command prompt using `dir` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to look at `doskey`, which is a command built in to `cmd` in Windows XP onwards (and was a DOS utility in previous versions).

Simple usage example: `doskey dirw=dir /w`

Now using `dirw` will instead call `dir /w`.